# Found error in my journal paper, correct preprints?

Tags: journals, authorship

I found an error in one of my journal papers several months after publication.  The error doesn't affect my results, but I mistook the prior state of the art.

I misreported a feature of a prior work. I said it has a feature that it does not actually have and therefore improperly credited it as holding the previous record for best performance for products with that feature. As a result, I credited the wrong prior work for setting the prior state of the art. My paper boasts a 2x improvement over prior work but it should be 4x because the performance of the real prior record holder isn't as good.

I've already emailed the journal editor and waiting for a response about whether I can/should issue an erratum.

My question to the community is: Should I fix the preprints that I uploaded to various repositories (techRxiv, research gate, etc), regardless of what the editor decides? Is this a common way to address publication errors? Would it create confusion if the latest preprint upload date is several months newer than the published paper?

Answer (score 1):

I have not had this exact experience, but I do not think that fixing the preprint would cause confusion. You could add a note highlighting the change and indicating that it is not yet reflected in the published version.

If you're concerned about running afoul of some fine print from the publisher, you can always wait. Since this doesn't affect your results, there is probably no harm in being cautious. But *as long as you are complying with the journal's requirements* for preprints, updating it to reflect a minor correction should not be an issue. You've already taken the step of informing the journal for an "official" correction and will change the preprint eventually anyway. You should double check that there are no rules about modifying the preprint after publication though.